# If GRUB2 doesn't play well with my PC, will an alternate bootloader work?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub2, acer

I have an Acer Spin 1 (trying to run *only* Ubuntu), and I've read that grub doesn't work well on that machine. This seems to be true, as I have spent hours fruitlessly trying to install it after installing Ubuntu without a bootloader.

If GRUB2 is a no-go, what are the chances that something like LILO will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think *"something like LILO"* will work because it's old (no more developed[1]) and your hardware is new.

You certainly will have more chances with a ***brand-new*** bootloader like systemd-boot. To be honest, *systemd-boot* isn't a bootloader but a bootmanager and that is what you need because you have an EFI machine...

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LILO_(boot_loader)